# when touch back button on android how to quit the app by cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

A game created by cocos2dx. In active scene, when I touch the back button on android, how can i quit it!
can give same example?

Comment: I use this "android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());" solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Version cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4 and cocos2d-x-2.1.4

in our Layer.h:

```
    ...
    void keyBackClicked();
    ...
```

in our Layer.ccp:

```
    Layer::init(){
    ...  
    this->setKeypadEnabled(true);  
    ...
    }

    void Layer::keyBackClicked() {
         CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you are in a position if you click back then you are navigated to the previous screen where you started off your game application right? Then here is the solution: after navigating to the new `intent`, the previous screen gets in an inactive state in android [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) you can find that the previous screen goes to a invisible state. Now we can use `onPause()` method to close the hidden activity. In the same class add this code and your app should be closed when you press back `button`.

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

When you click any button and go to a new intent the application goes to the invisible state and the onPause() method is triggered automatically and it closes the same intent in background.

Comment: yes, i try this, it work! but when next enter the game, it will auto quit.

Comment: @minji_LT: You mean when user enters next level you want to quit by pressing back right?

Comment: @minji_LT: Here is a thing. When somebody puts some effort and your problem is solved even if partially solved then please don't hesitate to vote-up the answer. If your problem is fully solved then don't forget to accept the answer. This is the least we can do right?

Answer (score 0):

Override `backKeyClicked()` method in your layer.

Don't forget to add `this->isKeypadEnabled(true)` in `init` method of layer.

In you `backKeyClicked` method, you can switch it to previous scene or whatever you wanna do.

Comment: I use this "android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());" solve my problem